# Making Google Desktop to Index Archived Mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, google-desktop-search

As title, currently in my Google Desktop, I can't find the archived email stored in outlook 2007, anything I should do to make GDS index those emails?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this mean you can't find where Outlook is configured to archive the mail?

Comment: I've modified my question for clarification. Thanks.